# Clear user details/credentials

Tags: google-cast

Is it possible to the clear the user data for a particular app such as Netflix using the API or some other method other than manually doing it on the remote. the Use case would be after a period of time or when someone leaves the hotel room/ air b & b.

Thank you

Researched but haven’t found a solution